# JavaScriptの書き方（たくさんの変数あり）

Tags: javascript

下はあるjsファイルの冒頭の部分です。
この下に3000行くらいのコードが続きます（そこに具体的な処理の内容が記載されている）。
このようにtとかaとかの短い引数や変数を羅列したコードをよく見かけます。
これはどのような書き方（？）なのでしょうか？
何か参考になる情報はありますか？

```
! function (t) {
        function e(a) {
            if (n[a]) return n[a].exports;
            var i = n[a] = {
                exports: {},
                id: a,
                loaded: !1
            };
            return t[a].call(i.exports, i, i.exports, e), i.loaded = !0, i.exports
        }
        var n = {};
        return e.m = t, e.c = n, e.p = "", e(0)
    }([function (t, e, n) {
        t.exports = n(1)
    }, function (t, e, n) {
        var a;
        a = n(2), window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            return new a
        }, !1)
    }, function (t, e, n) {
        var a, i, r, o, s, u, l, h = function (t, e) {
            return function () {
                return t.apply(e, arguments)
            }
        };
        l = n(3), o = n(28), u = n(33), i = n(36), s = n(38), a = n(44), r = function () {
            function t() {
    //...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイル全体がそのような記述であるなら、**UglifyJS** などを使った「最適化(圧縮)」や「難読化」を施した結果だと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。冒頭のコードの下には、クラス名やメソッド名などが書かれていて、何となくわかる部分もあります。

Comment: その場合、おそらくですが最適化/難読化されたライブラリを使い、コードを新たに書いてパッキング(ライブラリを展開して埋め込み)はしたけれど、再度最適化していない、というようなことではないでしょうか。なので追加分だけ分かるようなことがある。
あるいは、それらのクラスやメソッドはモジュールからexportしていて、他の部分から参照されるため最適化の対象外になった、という可能性もあります。具体例があればもうちょっと確かなことが言えるかもしれません。

Comment: @rugamaga  ありがとうございます！元のコードを参考にしていので、復元したいと思っております。最適化されていない部分があるせいか今のところうまくいきませんが。